# writing filter using a single foldr call?

Tags: filter, scheme, racket, fold

Objective is to write filter function with only a single foldr call with no recursion or any other higher-order procedures (map, andmap, apply, etc).

Currently I am using

```
  (define (filter ps xs)
    (if (empty? xs)
        ps
        (foldr (lambda (p y)
                 (if (andmap p xs)
                     (cons p y)
                     y))
               '()
               ps)))
```

however it is using `andmap` function which is considered a higher-order procedure

Goal is to have

```
(filter positive? '(-1 2 3 4 -5 -6)) 
=> '(2 3 4)
```

with a single call of foldr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misunderstand how `foldr` works, you have to pass the *list* to process as the last parameter, and for implementing filter, apply `ps` on each element you want to test. Better try something like this:

```
(define (filter ps xs)
  (foldr (lambda (p y)
           (if (ps p)
               (cons p y)
               y))
         '()
         xs))
```

It works as expected:

```
(filter positive? '(-1 2 3 4 -5 -6)) 
=> '(2 3 4)
```

Comment: How would I implement it this way if ps is a list consisting procedures, so that the returned list only keeps element that are true for all procedures? I can only use a single call of foldr.

Comment: That's trickier, you'd have to traverse the list of procedures in the `if` condition. Replace `(ps s)` with `(andmap (lambda (f) (f p)) ps)`

Comment: Well yea that's gonna be a problem, I can only use a single call of foldr and nothing else (can't use andmap and no recursion), else it would be a lot less confusing.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a homework assignment. I can see why `foldr` was chosen, but for the sake of seeing it implemented with a `foldl` here you go

```
(define (filter f xs)
  (reverse (foldl (λ (x ys) (if (f x) (cons x ys) ys))
                  null
                  xs)))

(filter positive? '(-1 2 3 4 -5 -6)) 
;=> '(2 3 4)
```

`foldl` has the distinct advantage over `foldr` in that it is implemented with a proper tail call.